# Exts 4.2 minified file size 1.2+ MB

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am new to Extjs and Sencha CMD. I am using Extjs v4.2.0 and CMD v 3.2.1.
I am trying to minify extjs and my app in .js file, it ends up 1.2 MB in size.
Is there any docs,that explains on what should the CMD include based on the requires,controller,view,model and store?

Comment: Sencha CMD includes only classes which you declare in the require property (+ your classes).